# MPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate not working under 1.0 value (for slowmotion video)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediaplayercontroller

I wanted to play the video 5 times slower (mp4 video, local file), to get slowmotion effect, but it simply does not work.
For values above 1.0, for example 2.0f, it works correctly, playing the video 2 times faster.

This is the code I used to play video on 20% speed:

```
[_player prepareToPlay];
[_player play];
[_player setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.2f];
```

With this code, video plays on normal rate (1.0f), ignoring my 0.2f value.

iOS 6.1.3
XCode 4.6.2

Testing on device.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely matters when you call

`[_player setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.2f];`

I've run into similar issues.  I have setup a `UISlider` to manage the playback speed.  If I change the speed while the video is actually playing it does in fact change the speed.  However, if I pause it and then hit the play button again, it reverts to standard 1x speed.  Even if I use

`MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`

to listen for the playing update and then call

`[_player setCurrentPlaybackRate:x.xx];`.

I believe the player sets its own value with the play mechanic, I'm trying to figure out a work around currently to get this to update to my `UISlider` value when play is hit.  Currently it's overriding the value for whatever reason.

Though this isn't a complete solution, I hope this helps you move forward.